# writing raw html to a response object in rails (using ActionDispatcher::Response)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

How to write the response from the controller using the ActionDispatch::Response object. There seems to be no api that does http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Response.html.

The below code works which does not use any view. Is the same can be achived using a response object. The reason being having a necessity to write some binary data to html(which is required for the the current rails app being written)

```
class HelloController < ApplicationController
  def index
    render :text => "hello" # want to use ActionDispatch::Response object instead of this
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you taken a look at [send_data](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Streaming/send_data)? It may be what you're looking for.